# Screenshot of entire SharePoint Page

Tags: 2013

The answer may be very simply, but I couldn't find any solution which meets my requirements.

I'm trying to make a screenshot (grab entire screen and save it for example as image or PDF) of a SharePoint 2013 Page (much content -> scrolling required) and I've tested several tools and Add-Ons for doing this job, but couldn't find any tool which grabs the entire screen without losing any components of SharePoint (e. g. SharePoint Tiles) or showing several components (e. g. the fixed top bar of SharePoint) for more than one time.

I would be really thankful if someone could suggest me any way how to solve my problem. Please include Browser name and its version for ADD-on solutions.

Comment: You can use snaggit 10 software to get whole screenshot of the page. It will work with all browsers

Comment: Thanks for your commet. Is there any portable version of? I don't have the required rights to install it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question isn't directly about SharePoint and could just be considered as a "How can I take a screenshot of a site"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the zoom option in your browser till you get a good fit of the page you want to screen capture, then just use Print Screen and place it in mspaint and crop any extra areas. This is the simplest way IMO and you don't need to install any other software on your machine

Comment: Would give a fairly low resolution on the output image though

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well I worked like this before I asked this question here, but as Robert said, the resolution is kinda low. Secondly the Screen I am working on is already a 15", what is making the "getting everything on one page" even harder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking here, you should have used Google:

https://www.google.nl/search?q=capture+whole+web+page

**My tools**

[TechSmiths Snaggit](https://support.gyazo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204281039-How-do-I-use-Gyazo-GIF-) used to be my favorite, then switched to:

- FireShot - http://web-screen-capture.soft112.com/
  is a plugin/extension for all browsers and worth the $40 for a life-time license

These do not capture the whole webpage, but are my favorites:

- ShareX - https://getsharex.com/
  Needs a local install, but great for auto saving screenshots
- Gyazo - http://gyazo.com
  Very simple as Browser plugin, Not as powerful as FireShot,
  but their [local install version](https://support.gyazo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204281039-How-do-I-use-Gyazo-GIF-) is great for creating Animated-GIFs
- Video capture
  Same story, switched from Techsmith-Camtasia to [Screen-Cast-O-matic](http://screencast-o-matic.com/home) because it was just very easy to use. And at $15 a year for the Pro version, a lot cheaper.

If you want to automate Web-Page capture with a Batch script (Windows), there is a Freeware oldie: [WebScreenCapture](http://web-screen-capture.soft112.com/)
But it does **not** scroll the WebPage!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I of course used google before mate, but after ~10 different ADD-on and Software attempts I gave it up. Fireshot didn't work for me, cuz it displayed the fixed SharePoint bar from top for several times, also in the body (cuz scrolling down takes bar with it). I can't install local softwares due to lack of Admin rights on my companies laptop.